# How do I set the players "tame" score to 1 if they tame a wolf?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and I need to give the player +1 for taming a wolf but I don't know the command. All I know is `/scoreboard objectives add tame {part I don't know}`. Then some command block that gives them the point. Then maybe `testfor @p[score=tame=1]`.

All the commands I tried are:

- `testfor @p[team=start]`
- `scoreboard objectives add tame{I don't know}`
- `scoreboard players set @p{I don't know}`

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. `stat.useItem.minecraft.bone` doesn't work. You can track number of animals *bred*, but not how many animals you've *tamed*.

Comment: It's not possible. Minecraft does not track number of mobs tamed. The closest thing that is tracked to the ## of mobs tamed is the ## of mobs  bred.

Comment: Actually.. Can you track wolves based on the name of the owner? (If this is possible, then you'll have to setup a detector for every single player); along the lines of `@e[type=TamedWolf,Owner=...]` or something like that.

Comment: Can it be ,Owner=@p]

Answer (score 3):

This solution is based on defining the person closest to a wolf when it first sits down as it's tamer.

The reason for this workaround is twofold:

- Players don't have a "wolves tamed" statistic
- Wolves don't have a "tamed" entry in their NBT, and it's not possible to look for an empty "ownerUUID"

Start with the following commands.

```
/scoreboard objective add isTamed dummy
/scoreboard objective add wolvesTamed dummy Wolves Tamed
```

This will add an objective that is used to check for tamed wolves, and another for the players.

Now run the following commands on a clock

```
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Wolf] isTamed 1 {Sitting:1}
/scoreboard players add @e[type=Wolf,score_isTamed_min=3] isTamed -1
/execute @e[type=Wolf,score_isTamed=1,score_isTamed_min=1] scoreboard players add @p[r=3] wolvesTamed 1
```

This will continuously increase the `isTamed` objective by 1 as long as the wolf sits. This is followed by decreasing it by one if it is greater than 2 (this is not technically necessary, but keeps the scores low)

In addition, the player closest to a wolf (and within 3m) with an `isTamed` score of exactly 1 (which can only happen when it first sits down) will have their `wolvesTamed` score increased by 1.

There might be an issue with the last command, because wolves might not be able to use "cheats". In this case, you would need to find a way to use the `/trigger` command instead.

Comment: +1 This may work... Except tamed wolf counts; the scoreboard scores will go haywire if two (or more) guys stood inside (or close to) each other when the wolves are asked to sit (doesn't matter who tamed which one). Of course this will work, but it won't count properly in such event. Basically: Nice workaround, but it only works if players are not close to each other when the sitting happens as it may award the score to the wrong person.

Comment: Very nice. Out of curiosity though, what happens in the event of breeding? Obviously not part of the original question, but sit a thought :) +1